# How to add "application/json" inside "multipart/form-data" with swagger 3, spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, postman, swagger, swagger-ui

To call the api I need 2 parts file (file type) and post (type application/json), so how to let swagger3 know I want to send post with Content-type of application/json.
Here is my code

```
@Operation(
        description = "Tạo bài viết, quyền USER/ADMIN",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = PostResponseDTO.class)), responseCode = "200")})
@ApiResponses(
        value = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Thành công"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Chưa xác thực", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class))),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Truy cập bị cấm", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class))),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Không tìm thấy", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class)))
        })
@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')")
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(
        mediaType = "multipart/form-data",
        schema = @Schema(implementation = FormUpload.class)
))
public PostResponseDTO createPost(
        @RequestPart(name = "post") @Valid PostRequestDTO postRequestDTO,
        @RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile[] file) throws IOException {

    if (!(filesService.notEmpty(file) && filesService.isSingleFile(file) && filesService.isImageFile(file[0]) && filesService.maxSize(file[0], 5))) {
    }
    return postService.save(postRequestDTO, file);
}

record FormUpload(MultipartFile[] file, PostRequestDTO postRequestDTO) {}
```

This is how i call the api using postman:
[image]